# Scan for number in a page

Tags: javascript, html, regex

How can I scan an entire html web page for occurrences of *numeric values*  ? An efficient solution in **javascript** is needed.

Comment: Using regular expressions would be my first choice. `\d+`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with the numbers.

```
var text = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
var numbers = text.match(/\d+/g);
alert(numbers.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $($(this).text().match(/\d+/g)).each(
            function() {
                alert(this);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("html").html()` will return the whole page as HTML source. I think that CHOCY need just innerHTML() values of each element. The above code example would alert all values including element attribute values for example...

Example:

```
<div style="width:550px; left-padding:5px">
  <div class="demo-box1">Demonstration Box 66</div>
</div>
```

Would return:

550, 5, 1, 66 ... am I right?

Comment: Yes, but "html" gets the head too. And you don't need a 4,000 line library to get either the text or innerHTML.